# How to use Team: Signin with VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops, tfvc, azure-devops-extensions, azure-repos

I am running into an error message which I don't understand while trying the following commande:
**Team: Signin**
It used to work back then but now I have an error message.
[Error message picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaQah.png)

1. Info:

   - Version: 1.44.2 (user setup)
   - Commit: ff915844119ce9485abfe8aa9076ec76b5300ddd
   - Date: 2020-04-16T16:36:23.138Z
   - Electron: 7.1.11
   - Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
   - Node.js: 12.8.1
   - V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
   - OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363

I can provide more informations if needed, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the tag of the question, you are using TFVC version control. With TFVC, the extension uses information about the current workspace to determine how to connect to Azure DevOps Services (or your Team Foundation Server). Workspaces can be created using the Visual Studio IDE, Eclipse or with the JetBrains IDEs (e.g, Android Studio, IntelliJ).

**Note**: At this time, you will need to have a ***local*** TFVC workspace already available on your local machine. More information about the difference between the two types (and how to determine which one you're using) can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-repos-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#what-is-the-difference-between-a-local-and-server-workspace-how-can-i-tell-which-one-im-working-with).

In order to provide TFVC support in Visual Studio Code, the extension relies on the use of a **TF command line client**. Therefore, you will need to have one already installed and configured. TFVC support will not work without an available command line client.

About `sign in` ：  In order for the extension to be activated, a repository folder must be opened. The extension won't be activated if only a single file in the repository is opened.

You can refer to [Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) Support](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-repos-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#tfvc-command-line-client) for details.

In addition, here is a detailed [guide](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/step-by-step-procedures-to-integrate-visual-studio-team-services-vsts-with-visual-studio-code-vscode-for-sharepoint-framework-spfx-projects/) that describes how to solve the error you encountered. In this guide, the old version of the azure repo extension(Visual Studio Team Services) is used. Please view step 16.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, you've been very helpful and I managed to fix my issue with your help and the documentation provided.
Thank you very much !